# Wpf Application Entity Framework sqlite

Tags: wpf, sqlite, entity-framework, setup-deployment

I firstly wanted to info that I am currently using Visual studio 2017 with .net 4.6.1 version.

I create a wpf application in which I used Entity framework to manager the sqlite database.

My Dbcontext class is as Below.

```
 
public class DbContextClass :DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<HomeModel> Home { get; set; } 

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "/EfCrud";
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);            
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Data source={path}/Database.db");
        }
    }
```

And I calling a function inside the ViewModel to Ensure that Database should be there when Application loads in the memory. My code is as below.

```
  try
            {
                using (var context = new DbContextClass())
                {
                    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception E)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(E.ToString());
            }
            CrudClass.ShowEntries(HomeList);
            IsVisible = true;
        }
```

Now the problem is, When I run my application in Visual Studio that the about code create Database in the specified location when no database is present.
But When I create Setup of my application and try to run it into the system, It gives me exception and my application ultimately terminated.

The Exception message Which I got is as follow :-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhkdG.png)

please let me know the issue and how can I fixed this issue.

I tried installing different version of Entity framework but didn't able to get rid of the Exception.
I wanted to know the reason for which I am getting such Exception and how can I fix the issue.

Comment: Library e_sqlite3 not found... do you have the necessary dlls with your installation on the target machine ?

Comment: how can I check it sir??

Comment: Check the installation folder (Your app folder). atleast these should be there: System.Data.SQLite.dll,  System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll, System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll

Comment: Sorry sir, but after adding above mentioned dlls I am still getting the same exceptions.

Comment: Have you manually added the dll? Better to use nuget. I think Install-Package System.Data.SQLite

Comment: Yes sir I installed through Nuget.  Actually sir in Visual studio when I run my application then everything works fine but when I create setup and install it to my system then only getting this error

Comment: When you say: installer/setup, what are you doing? because if you have added EF SQLite dependencies over nuget, this should not happen

Comment: sir I created the setup (.exe) of my project and then install that exe file into my desktop. after running the installed application i am getting this error.

Comment: I would suggest you use entityframework.sqlite package instead, might be much easier. Have a look at this example, starting from 3m15s at https://youtu.be/b1X7T8wNsJE